# connecting to a mysql database remotely

Tags: mysql, database

What I would like to do is connect to a database that runs a website. Then copy the contents of that database to another database, on a different server. Can this be done?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done and there are different ways to do it. I'll list 3 different ways

1. Run `mysqldump -h<source host> | mysql -h<target host>`. You'll have to read up on the mysqldump options to decide which you need to add and you probably need to put options for user, password and databases as well.
2. Copy all files that mysql uses and put them on the new host. As long as the new server is configured the same way it will work
3. Use Perconas [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/). This is probably the best option if the database is large. The database can still run while the backup is being made. This option will create an exact copy of the database and that may or may not be wanted.

Generally if the database is small option 1 is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends on how the database is set up.

Most databases that run behind a web server will not be accessible externally, for security reasons.  Your best bet, assuming you have access to the server, is to login to the shell and dump the database.  MySQL has the tool `mysqldump` to help with this.  In a pinch:

```
mysqldump -u username -p schemaname > yourdatabasedump.sql
```

Alternatively, you could install `PhpMyAdmin` on your server (assuming PHP is enabled) and dump the database from there.

Importing is the opposite.  Get shell access on the other server and do something like this...  First, create your schema:

```
mysql -u someuser -p

 > CREATE DATABASE schemaname;
 > exit
```

Then import.

```
mysql -u someuser -p schemaname < yourdatabasedump.sql
```

Comment: Footnote: If you happen to be doing this as part of a WordPress migration from a very old version, you may have to do a bunch more hacking.  I've given you the simple invocations as a starter.